# Does Lambda shutdown the entire container when the traffic is zero?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dropwizard, serverless

It is said that lambda shutdown the container when there is no traffic and when first request came after long time, there is a cold start problem. Is that right? Eg. If I am running a drop wizard application on AWS lambda, will the server gets shutdown if no traffic is coming and it will again starts the server on first request? Is that correct?

Or it does not shutdown the server running in the container but does something else? Please explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes that is correct, once a lambda function does not receive any traffic for a period of time (in my experience approximately 15 mins), the container is destroyed and the next request will result in a new container being started (known as a cold-start).

One thing to note however, is that lambda containers can be shut down at any time between requests, so even if you have constant traffic to the lambda, you may still experience the occasional cold-start.

Additionally, each lambda container will only process a single request at a time, so if you have one lambda container which is "warm" and two requests come in simultaneously, one request will be processed by the pre-warmed lambda, and the other will encounter a cold-start.

Comment: The word "instance" should be replaced with "container" here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but hopefully, after past years both of you got more details on the Lambda Container Lifecycle.

There is an INIT step, where the container is prepared, or warmed, for the INVOKE. The Cold-Start, as you mentioned, is this INIT step. Then it gets ready for the INVOKE calls, and keeps up, while there is traffic to it. But there is another step of the cycle, the SHUTDOWN. And I'm trying to explore it better.

If the container gets IDLE for an amount of time, it is destroyed, but as far as I understood, Amazon Service calls a SIGINT kill to it.

If I have a function in my script that could be called as long as the SIGNINT arrives, that would be great. For instance, to explore this step, I'm keeping a buffer where I store content of many calls that arrives through the INVOKE. My idea was to just store it at the INVOKE, and just at the SHUTDOWN time, I would flush the data stored as .CSV and upload to a S3 Bucket. Considering the cycle described it would work.

I did some tests exploring this, but until now no success yet.

Something else I tried that might give some clue on the why the SHUTDOWN flush didn't work. I added a scheduler to the script, so every minute it checks if the container is idle for more than 5 min, and then it flush my buffer when true. If I call the INVOKE 6 min after the first INVOKE, I can see the buffer was flushed, so the schedule worked. But the .CSV, expected at the S3 Bucket wasn't there.

I'm not sure about the reason yet, but I believe it is about permission. If I'm right, the container loses the permissions as soon the INVOKE ends. So anything I do in BACKGROUND gets limited, and I cannot interface with other Amazon Services.

Any clues?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35155164)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).